# How correctly add WinUI control to C# UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I try to add Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView in my C# UWP project. But when I debug my app LoadComponent(...) throws XamlParseException:

[image]

I follow all the steps described in [Microsoft WinUI Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started).  I don’t need to create WinUI project.
My project properties:

[image]

**[My project repos](https://github.com/pnfstas/SqlDbObjectsUwpPublic.git) Here the minidump is committed.**

My project links:

[image]

Application XAML:

```
<Application
    x:Class="SqlDBObjects.SqlDbApplication"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:SqlDBObjects">
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My main window content is custom control based on ContentControl. It’s XAML fragment:

```
<ContentControl
    x:Class="SqlDBObjects.SqlDbContentControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:mctk="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:SqlDBObjects"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="SQLDBContentControl"
    Background="LightGray"
    Loaded="OnLoaded">
    ...
    <muxc:TreeView
        Name="DBObjectTree"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="White"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DBOBJECT_TEMPLATE}"
        Expanding="OnTreeViewExpanding">
    </muxc:TreeView>
    ...
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: https://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2020/08/uwp-navigationview-cannot-find-resource.html "Fix: You will need to add XamlControlsResources to your app.xaml file"  Google is your friend.

Comment: XamlControlsResources just added, but is not successfully.

Comment: Are you sure you actually installed the `Microsoft.UI.XAML` pacakge? As I don't see it listed in your installed packages... I'd double check the Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: Sorry, I remove this package. But when it was added, the exception was also thrown. It was the same result, when I add Windows App SDK.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I debug my app LoadComponent(...) throws XamlParseException

I could reproduce your problem when missing add `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />`. please follow Getting started with the [Windows UI 2 Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started) document, and install `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` nuget version 2.7. then build your app. if the problem still exist, please clean your project or remove bin and obj folder.

**Update**

The problem is you custom app's entry point as `SqlDbApplication`, and  this causes winui `XamlControlsResources` can't load correctly. please feel free post this problem in WinUI github issue box. Currently there is a workaround that is edit `SqlDbApplication` to **`App`** as the app's default entry point. (please don't forget update the entry-point within package manifest)

Comment: I have done so: reinstall NuGet package Microsoft.UI.Xaml 2.7, XamlControlsResources reference is just added in my Application.xaml, remove bin and obj folders and rebuild project. But exception is still thrown.

Comment: Could you mind share us with [mcve]?

Comment: I add link to my project repos and this exception minidump.

Comment: @Stanislav I have updated the answer, do you have any updates?

Comment: Nico Zhu - MSFT, thank your for all replies. I have done that changes: rename my application class anywhere in my project and in manifest, clean and rebuild project. But exception is still thrown. I update my project repo.

Comment: Have you edit the app's entrypoint on the project's manifest file ?

Comment: Nico Zhu - MSFT,  I correct entry point in the manifest file - the namespace was wrong. But it not solve the problem.  I update my project repo.

Comment: Can you share the link below?

Comment: Nico Zhu - MSFT, [My project repo](https://github.com/pnfstas/SqlDbObjectsUwpPublic)